# predicates not applied on fetchRequest in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I am using `core data` with `swift 3.0`.In my Core Data I have an entity 'User', that has three properties 'name' , `age`, and 'address' defined as String.

[image]

I want to check user name is already exists or not in `core data entity` . My code is

```
func checkUserAlreadyExists(name:String) -> Bool
    {

        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<UserModel>(entityName: "User")
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name = %@",name)
//I have also tried this 
//fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@",name)

        do {
            let arrUsers:[UserModel] = try managedContext!.fetch(fetchRequest)
            print(arrUsers.count)
            if(arrUsers.count>0)
            {
               return true
            }
            else
            {
                return false
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            return false
        }

    }
```

I have just enter an object have name **test** but it didn't fetch and **arrUsers.count** always returns **0** .

I have insert data with below code

```
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {return}

            let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
            let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "User",in: managedContext)!

            let user:UserModel = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,insertInto: managedContext) as! UserModel
            user.name = "test"
            user.address = "test address"
            user.age = "25"


            do {
                try managedContext.save()
                getAllUsersFromCoreData()

            } catch let error as NSError
            {
                print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
```

I have go through lot of `Questions` on `stackoverflow` but didn't find soluation

Comment: You can use Predicate like this.  NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[cd] %@", "searchtext")

Comment: it's not work for me@ArunK

Comment: Show the code that calls `checkUserAlreadyExists`, including where it gets the value of the `name` argument.

Comment: I am inserting static value on a button pressed like "test" . I also double check(no error message getting and also get the value from `coredata` ) value insert successfully . after then i am calling `checkUserAlreadyExists`, then it gives me **zero object in array***@TomHarrington

Comment: It strange i don't kown why this happen@TomHarrington

Comment: I have facing same problem some time ago but didn't have any solution